# Xcode 11 | Running command instruments -s devices | CoreData XRPackageModel Error

Tags: ios, instruments, xcode11

With Xcode 11 when I run this command `instruments -s devices` in terminal, I get this error.

`CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'`

Comment: Have you checked that the file `XRPackageModel 9.0.omo` actually exists in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd`?